# how to decompile smart contract bytecode?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, fallback-function, decompilers

I don't want the whole bytecode to solidity.
I just want that bytecode have fallback function and it's content.
is feature in the bytecode about fallback function?

about external contract call, external contract's address is existed in bytecode?

Comment: I didn't try but there's https://github.com/comaeio/porosity

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear, but as indicated elsewhere on this board, there are currently a few alternatives in terms of EVM decompiler:

- [JEB](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/blog/ethereum-smart-contract-decompiler/) (recommended by the Porosity folks, that tool being deprecated/unmaintained), pro tool, they have a free demo
- [Ethervm.io](https://ethervm.io/decompile), a SaaS portal