# Lost my deployed contract code. Anyway of viewing this?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-deployment, explorers

Long story short I lost the contract code that I deployed. This is deployed to the live net. Is there anyway of being able to view the source of the contract code that has been deployed?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28877/how-to-decompile-smart-contract-bytecode

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-can-you-decompile-a-smart-contract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the address of the contract on the live net you can get its bytecode and decompile with this tool https://github.com/comaeio/porosity Here is an example from their README:

```
> porosity --abi $abi --code $code --decompile --verbose 0

Porosity v0.1 (https://www.comae.io)
Matt Suiche, Comae Technologies <support@comae.io>
The Ethereum bytecode commandline decompiler.
Decompiles the given Ethereum input bytecode and outputs the Solidity code.

Attempting to parse ABI definition...
Success.

Hash: 0x5FD8C710
function withdrawBalance() {
      if (msg.sender.call.gas(4369).value(store[msg.sender])()) {
         store[msg.sender] = 0x0;
      }
}


L3 (D8193): Potential reetrant vulnerability found.

LOC: 5
Hash: 0xC0E317FB
function addToBalance() {
      store[msg.sender] = store[msg.sender] + msg.value;
      return;
}


LOC: 4
Hash: 0xF8B2CB4F
function getBalance(address) {
      return store[arg_4];
}


LOC: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out tools like [JEB Decompiler](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb/evm) or [Ethervm.io](https://ethervm.io/decompile).

JEB is interactive decompiler that produces very readable code, some of which can be modified (e.g. variable and function names).

Ethervm is a free web portal. The output is not as clean but it is quite convenient to use for one-off decompilations.